# boost/static_assert.hpp includes itself

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I downloaded the latest and greatest boost for Windows, namely 1.65.1 (zip file).  Compiling a project, I now get the error that static_assert.hpp includes itself. Sure enough, here it is in its entirety:

```
//Copyright (c) 2008-2016 Emil Dotchevski and Reverge Studios, Inc.
//Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
//file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

#ifndef BOOST_QVM_STATIC_ASSERT
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#define BOOST_QVM_STATIC_ASSERT BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT
#endif
```

The previous version I have, 1.62, has a static_assert.hpp that is loaded with tons of macros and upper-case jibberish.

What do I need to do?

EDIT: I downloaded the boost_1_65_1.7z archive, and it's fine. Problem solved. Can someone report this to the boost people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed using the .7z archive instead of the .zip, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have conflicting include paths.
There are multiple `static_assert.hpp` files in boost, contents of `static_assert.hpp` you pasted are from `boost/qvm`.
`boost/static_assert.hpp` does have tons of macros even in 1.65.1.

I suggest you include `static_assert.hpp` as `boost/static_assert.hpp` to avoid the the include path confusion.

Comment: No,as I said, the contents I pasted are from boost/static_assert.hpp. The file is faulty.in the .zip archive. In the .7z archive it is correct.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't say that. You explained that those are the contents of static_assert.hpp and you didn't specify a path.

Comment: @JiveDadson the code you pasted is (obvious by just looking at the macros) from [boost/qvm/static_assert.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/boost/qvm/static_assert.hpp).