# Boost: how to handle its nested include files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have a Hello World program that uses

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
```

I set the Additional Include Directories and this file is found.  Its first include file is

```
#include <boost/process/args.hpp>
```

and that is found O.K.  It in turn has an include file

```
#include <include/boost/process/detail/basic_cmd.hpp>
```

that throws an error

C1083: Cannot open include file: 'include/boost/process/detail/basic_cmd.hpp'

which is correct in its way - there is no lower level include file!

Manually changing this to

```
#include <boost/process/detail/basic_cmd.hpp>
```

allows that file to be found, but its child then throws the same type of error.  What Visual Studio setting handles these nested includes automatically?

Comment: Which version of boost is this? I don't have the `include/` prefix in `args.hpp` in version 1.65.0

Comment: vcpkg built 1_65_1 by default.  Maybe I need to go back to ver 64_x?  Or as you say 1.65.0

Comment: More like broken whatever that vcpkg thing is. Just get the canon sources from boost proper. | 1.65.0 is definitely a poor choice, there's a number of significant (considering how quickly that bugfix release came out) bugs that are addressed in 1.65.1.

Comment: Maybe vcpkg is broken right now? https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg  But it seems to have potential - it built a Boost version without any hassle.  Now it only needs to build a working version :-)

Comment: From what I can see looking at boost's git history, that line has never referenced 'include/boost/...', it's always been 'boost/...' since that include [was added](https://github.com/boostorg/process/commit/46afca8239ce8a3b189c55ba86c2b9f3d21ed680#diff-15c6f83bf7aa1d1a14ff7300a269e306R14).  vcpkg must be doing something strange.

Comment: Wow!!! Never would have expected that.

Answer (score 0):

I too had include-file trouble with with the .zip file download.

[boost/static_assert.hpp includes itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290446/boost-static-assert-hpp-includes-itself)

Install boost using the .7z archive instead of the .zip. (Advice applies to 1.65 only.)